# Android Offline Apps using SQLite & Phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I developing offline apps using html / javascript / sqlite / phonegap to list data from sqlite database. i'm able to retrieve data from single table using wiki.phonegap

i found lots of articles / answer for to creating multiple tables, but not for retrieving data from multiple tables

kindly help me to retrieve data from multiple tables with some sample codes

Regards,
jay Chang

Answer (score 0):

Use this:`< html manifest="cache.manifest">` instead of `<html>`.And create a new file in the same directory named `cache.manifest`.

The contents of that file should look like this: `CACHE MANIFEST ## Required First Line index.html blabla.png`